# PLC ST programming

Tags: programming, plc

I have a mathematical model of two dynamic systems which I need to implement in PLC, but I don't know how to implement differential equations in structured text language.  Any suggestions on that will be helpful.

I have been thinking of converting differential equations to difference equation, but I don't have any idea how to do this.

$$\ddot{\Theta}=\dfrac{1-K_d\cdot\dot{\Theta}}{J} \tag {1} $$

$$\dot{i} = \dfrac{1}{L}(V-K_g k_f \dot{\Theta}-R i) \tag {2}$$

theta_dot_dot = 1/J*(1 - Kd*(theta_dot)) -------> Equation 1
i_dot = 1/L*(V - (Kg)*(kf)*(theta_dot) - R*i) --------> Equation 2

Comment: Post the equation to be converted. (Hit the edit link below your question.) It might not be possible. What brand and model of PLC too.

Comment: There are some things that PLC's are not really geared towards, such as multi-dimensional systems modeling. The best thing to do is to use something geared towards running this in C or Matlab and using a connector (some Fieldbus implementation) to tell the PLC what to do with the physical IO.

Comment: Almost the same as in C, even more similar is turbo pascal. There is also a PLC coder option in MATLAB. Show the equations of your system first, then make express them in Z-transform,...

Comment: @Transistor Im using OpenPLC and I will have to use that model in structured text language.

Comment: @RonBeyer I have modelled the system with PID controller in Simulink and it is working there. But I don't know how to write the equivalent one in structured text.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yeah I tried to use the PLC coder, but it couldn't convert the integrator blocks and throw those error.

Comment: You'd better to look some math book to solve this analytically or if not possible then use some numerical methods ala Runge-Kutta.

Comment: Simulink PLC Coder
Generate IEC 61131-3 Structured Text and Ladder Diagrams for PLCs and PACs

Answer (score 1):

$$\ddot{\Theta}=\dfrac{1-K_d\cdot\dot{\Theta}}{J} $$

$$J\ddot{\Theta}+K_d\cdot\dot{\Theta}-1=0 $$
$$\ddot{\Theta}+\dfrac{K_d}{J}\cdot\dot{\Theta}-\dfrac{1}{J}=0 $$
Discriminant : \$ \dfrac{K_d^2}{J^2} -\dfrac{4}{J}\$ is it positive?

$$\dot{i} = \dfrac{1}{L}(V-K_g k_f \dot{\Theta}-R i)$$

$$i = \dfrac{1}{L}\int(V-K_g k_f \dot{\Theta}-R i)dt$$
You solve the second equation with trapz rule.

$$Sample_{act}=\dfrac{1}{L}(V-K_g k_f \dot{\Theta}-R i)$$
$$i = i+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot T_{sample}\cdot (Sample_{act}+Sample_{old})$$
$$Sample_{old}=Sample_{act}$$